pytest not patching the function
Im building an FastAPI.
In the fast API, a one route is fetching a third party API for a state, this is wrapped in a get_state function
app/services/homeassistant.py
def get_state(entity_id: str ):
  entity = ha_client.get_entity(entity_id=entity_id)
  state = entity.get_state().state
  return state

Now when callling the route, get_state is called.
In my tests I need to mock the get_state call
def test_fetch_charger(mocker, client, charger):

  mock_response = "0.0"
  mocker.patch('app.services.homeassistant.get_state').return_value = mock_response

  response = client.get(f"/chargers/{charger.id}")

  assert response.status_code == 200

The test runs fine, but the result from get_state is the real result from the 3rd party API, not the mocked result. What am I doing wrong?

It's probably because you are mocking to the wrong location. The entrypoint of where you are making your API call is not aware of the location you are mocking via app.services.homeassistant.get_state. Revise where you are making your test call and you need to mock relative to those paths. When you're making API calls it is hard to mock granular methods deep in your code because the intent of your API tests is more black box testing. You should consider first unit testing at a lower level and then API testing to make it easier in your test design.

Alternatively, if this is a third party API that you want to stub out, you can consider some patterns in your API bootstrap that will help inject a mock client when bootstrapping your API. This way you can inject the mock client when the mock API kicks off in your tests. I usually use the dependency injection pattern to help in my overall design for things like this to make testing much easier.
